# Why has Pakistan bought J10C?

Tags: military, rafale, pakistan, india, chengdu-j-10

- [Pakistan inducts China-made J-10C fighter jets into PAF](https://www.thehindu.com/news/international/pakistan-inducts-china-made-j-10c-fighter-jets-into-paf/article65214438.ece)

According to the above article, the purchase of J10C was the response to India's purchase of Dassault Rafale.

Can anyone please explain why or how?

What were the factors that could have been motivated Pakistan's purchase of J10C aircraft from China to tackle Indian Rafales?

Comment: A main concern here is the radar and electronics. Radar on the JF-17 isn't the best due to its size limits, while the Russian radar on Su-30MKI isn't great, either. Both sides want to acquire fighters with ESA radars to gain advantage over the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **What were the factors that motivated Pakistan's purchase of J10C aircraft from China to tackle Indian Rafales?**

I've no insight into the motivations of Pakistan's senior officers but I imagine the following factors were important

- Multi-Role Combat Aircraft primarily intended for Air to Air operations.
- Similar max airspeed to Rafale.
- Better ceiling than Rafale.
- Ability to carry short and medium range air-to-air missiles.
- Cheap (1/4 the price of the Rafale)

Comment: cheap? or less expensive? :)

Comment: While some of the price difference might be because manufacturing in China is cheaper, I suppose most of it is actually the bells and whistles in the radome and avionics bay. Which makes a huge difference—these days fighters rarely get into manoeuvring combat for the raw performance to make a difference, usually they just fire missiles at each other at long range and then the biggest advantages are better radar, tracking software and countermeasures. And good AWACS downlink.

Comment: Maybe they finally found a market for their old planes. Perhaps in Ukrainia.

Comment: The point about multirole aircraft: weren't the F-16 already multirole?